# Horizontal line in the middle of the page

Tags: html, css

I want to have a horizontal line in the middle of the page. Some thing like

```
<div class="line">
  <hr>
</div>

.line {
  top: 50%;
}
```

But this doesn't work. I don't want to write the line by myself like

`<p> _______________________________________</p>`

Is there some way to center the hr?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need the line to be taken out of the normal flow of the document before you can set the top property.  Try this

```css
.line {
   position:absolute;
   width:100%;
   top: 50%;
}
```

```html
<hr class="line">
```

JS Fiddle:  https://jsfiddle.net/q9o5q70z/

Comment: This makes the hr line disappear altogether

Answer (score 2):

Use the `<hr>` tag, it's what it's for.

Comment: Oh my bad, I wanted to say hr, not br. I will correct. It still doesn't work btw

Comment: Aha ok, fair enough! :)

Comment: It won't position itself automatically of course. What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I want a straight line to always be in the middle of my page, no matter how big my page is. I was playing around and I saw that I can't center the hr  line at all. If I also add a text in that div... it sort of works but the line shortens

Answer (score 1):

Here's an example markup and stylesheet to get an `hr` working. I've set both widths to (roughly) take up the entire height of the page, then have a horizontal line to divide them.

Just run the snippet below, or check the [**Demo here**](https://jsfiddle.net/r6L4rmom/).

```css
div {
  height: 45vh;
}

span {
  position: relative;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%);
}

hr {
  height: 2px;
  background: red;
  border: 0;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span>some content</span>
</div>
<hr>
<div>
  <span>other content</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Wow this really works. If I take the text out from the spans, it's exactly what I needed. Thank you. It makes sense

Comment: @ScottMarcus, well most of the stuff is just to demo the `hr` with the rest of the content.